How to make treeview xct:Expander in xamarin forms?
I'm developing an android app with xamarin forms and I want to shape my menu like treeview like image below. 
I find xamarin community toolkit expander. It looks good and simple to use bu I have to use it like member of a listview.
That's where I'm stuck. I can't figure it out how to use it inside a listview. And there is another question is Expander is good choice for this menu view ? If you have another solution I will be glad to know.
My menu comes from a myservice and its look like this. :
[
 {
    "ADISOYADI": "USERNAME",
    "ADMINISTRATOR": "E",
    "ANAGRUPADI": "PERAKENDE YÖNETİMİ",
    "ANAGRUPKODU": "RETL",
    "ANDROID": "E",
    "BASLIK": "Stok Tanıtım Kartı",
    "DBNAME": "2413",
    "DELETE": "E",
    "EDIT": "E",
    "EPOSTA": "",
    "FIRM": 0,
    "GRUP": "KRT",
    "KULLANICI": "1",
    "OTURUMID": "",
    "PROGRAMKOD": "1",
    "SUBE": 0,
    "VIEW": "E"
 }   
]


from the docs: The Expander control is known to show unwanted behavior when used in a ListView or CollectionView. At this time we recommend not using a Expander in one of these controls.

Thank you @Jason  , what about I use collectionview inside expander?. I tried this and looks very good to me.
